# Inner Div 100% height exceeds parent div boundary

Tags: html, css

Please look into the 
[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tomalex0/N86Hu/)

to get a picture of issue i'm facing.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="outer cols-md-12">
   <div class="inner1">Inner1</div>
   <div class="inner2">Inner2</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I have two div inside a parent div . Parent div is having a height so as first inner div.
I'm giving 100% height from second inner div, but it exceeds the parent boundary.

I have given overflow hidden to  fix the issue, but is it the right way or anything else i need to do ?. I'm using bootstrap 3

Answer (score 0):

100% height assumes full height of the parent. In this case, inner2 will take 400px height. This is the reason that it overflows the outer div.

This can be fixed by allotting 50% height each to inner1 and inner2.

```
.outer {
    height:400px;
    width:400px;
    border:solid 1px red;
}    

.inner1 {
    height:50%;
    width:100%;
    border:solid 1px green;
}

.inner2 {      
    height:50%;
    width:100%;
    border:solid 1px yellow;
    background:beige;
}
```

Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GM9VQ/

Comment: Is there a way where i can use pixel height for  first inner div and 2nd div  take rest of the height. without using %.

Comment: I will try with % now.

Comment: You can use [css calc()](http://css-tricks.com/a-couple-of-use-cases-for-calc/) to resolve this issue. Check fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JR3uE/1/